# Array member name to write-host

Tags: powershell

```
$mbservers = @("server1", "server2")

Foreach ($mbserver in $mbservers) {
    #Check for reg key
    Invoke-Command -Computername $mbserver -Credential $credsschedtask -ScriptBlock {
        $regkey = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DisableLoopbackCheck"
        $checkregkey = (Test-Path $regkey)

        If ($checkregkey = "True") {
            Write-Host "'DisableLoopbackCheck' key exists on $mbserver".
        }
        ElseIf ($checkregkey = "False") {
            Write-Host "'DisableLoopbackCheck' key does not exist on $mbserver."
        }
        Else {
            Write-Host "Unable to confirm if 'DisableLoopbackCheck' key exists on $mbserver."
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to workout the `Write-Host` variable so it display's `server1` etc
(`Write-Host "'DisableLoopbackCheck' key exists on $mbserver".`)

Have tried the following in various ways:

- `For($i=0; $i -le $mbservers.getupperBound(0);$i++){`
- `write-host $mbservers[$i]`
- `write-host "line 2 :," $mbservers[$i]`

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Take a look at the [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6) modifier.  However, you should avoid `Write-Host` in your remote session (or in general, really), and create some [custom objects](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/) to return and format locally (e.g. with `Format-Table`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `If` and `ElseIf` comparisons don't function at the moment:

- `=` is used for setting values, `-eq` is used for comparing them
- `Test-Path` doesn't return a string `"True"`, it returns a bool `$True`

As a bool only has two states `$True` or `$False`, you only need `If/Else`:

```
Foreach ($mbserver in $mbservers) {
    #Check for reg key
    Invoke-Command -Computername $mbserver -Credential $credsschedtask -ScriptBlock {
        $checkregkey = Test-Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DisableLoopbackCheck"

        If ($checkregkey -eq $True) {
            Write-Host "'DisableLoopbackCheck' key exists on $mbserver".
        }
        Else {
            Write-Host "'DisableLoopbackCheck' key does not exist on $mbserver."
        }
    }
}
```